How to fix error: Library not loaded with Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift' when build My.xcframework
dyld[1057]: Library not loaded: @rpath/QKMRZScanner.framework/QKMRZScanner
Referenced from: <91E5FEEA-9636-3427-9091-3CE0BD89F1FF> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6F2F7639-08CB-48E6-98BA-A735D681658A/OScan.app/Frameworks/eIDCheckSDK.framework/eIDCheckSDK
Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/QKMRZScanner.framework/QKMRZScanner' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/QKMRZScanner.framework/QKMRZScanner' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6F2F7639-08CB-48E6-98BA-A735D681658A/OScan.app/Frameworks/QKMRZScanner.framework/QKMRZScanner' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6F2F7639-08CB-48E6-98BA-A735D681658A/OScan.app/Frameworks/eIDCheckSDK.framework/Frameworks/QKMRZScanner.framework/QKMRZScanner' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/QKMRZScanner.framework/QKMRZScanner' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/QKMRZScanner.framework/QKMRZScanner' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6F2F7639-08CB-48E6-98BA-A735D681658A/OScan.app/Frameworks/QKMRZScanner.framework/QKMRZScanner' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6F2F7639-08CB-48E6-98BA-A735D681658A/OScan.app/Frameworks/QKMRZScanner.framework/QKMRZScanner' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/QKMRZScanner.framework/QKMRZScanner' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/QKMRZScanner.framework/QKMRZScanner' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6F2F7639-08CB-48E6-98BA-A735D681658A/OScan.app/Frameworks/QKMRZScanner.framework/QKMRZScanner' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6F2F7639-08CB-48E6-98BA-A735D681658A/OScan.app/Frameworks/QKMRZScanner.framework/QKMRZScanner' (no such file)
I encountered this problem when building my framework, which uses QKMRZScanner inside.
But when I use pod for install my framework it works for iOS.
When integrating into React Native, I encountered the above error
Help me.
